# JavaScript/jQuery image slider issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8na2n5L2/

I'm trying to create an image slider, but for some reason just can't wrap my head around why this isn't working. I'm basically trying to create a slider where images come in from the right (off screen), and the center image gets pushed to the left (off screen). Then, when it comes time for that left image to go to the center again, it quickly goes back to the right again before going to the center.

jQuery(document).ready (function () {

```
var images = [];

//store the images in an array
jQuery('.main-image-slider').each( function () {
    images.push(jQuery(this));
});

var i = 0;
var max = images.length - 1;

setInterval( function () {
    if ( i > max) {
        i = 0;
    }

    images[i].removeClass('main-image-slider-left').addClass('main-image-slider-right').delay(100).queue(function () {
        images[i].removeClass('main-image-slider-right').addClass('main-image-slider-center').dequeue();
        i++;
    });


    if (images[i - 1]) {
        images[i - 1].removeClass('main-image-slider-center').addClass('main-image-slider-left');
    }


}, 3000);
```

});

Comment: Hey Jordan, it would be great if you can add a snippet or demo next time! Anyway it's a short example so I assume the error happens in your condition just before the increment. `if (images[i - 1])` - this can be a reference to the -1st element on the first iteration, which as we know will never exist since arrays are 0 indexed, and not -1. Instead, you could reference the previous image as i-1 while i > 0, and when i===0, the previous image will be on the index images[max]

Comment: Hope I make sense. I'd create `var previous = i > 0 ? images[i - 1] : images[max];` and then you won't need that faulty condition at all, and you can do `previous.removeClass()` etc

Comment: Note for debugging next time: the console should tell you what line it encountered the error on, that's the start. You could see that the condition was faulty. Because you are accessing an array entry and the console was complaining about `undefined` type, that means you are accessing an index which does not have a valid set to it. That's not an issue by itself, but then you were attempting to call a method `removeClass()` on it, and that's why the console complained - undefined does not have such property. From that, you can deduct that you are accessing non-existing element. Hope that helps

Comment: @lubos here's a fiddle incorporating Haizhou's answer https://jsfiddle.net/8na2n5L2/. I apologize, it did give me the line, but I forgot to include it. That issue is resolved now.

Comment: I got carried away a little bit, but here is a working version - http://codepen.io/lmenus/pen/rLeQey. Added there options too haha

Comment: @Lubos whoah that looks complicated

Comment: Not at all! Just keep learning and you will be soon doing much better! If you want I can help you with anything I know!

Comment: @Lubos Well, what's the advantage of this method? The jQuery method is only 27 lines of code, but yours is 154. By the way, is that ECMA6 typescript?

Comment: Yes, it's ES6. The lines of code are arguable, I have lots of comments there, while you're chaining some methods to use less space. That's not bad, it's just to highlight it can be misleading to judge purely by lines of code. In the end, the script will be minified anyway so what matters is the file size and complexity of the algorithm. Your method requires jQuery, which is quite a big library by itself. Then again, when you use it, any subsequent functions you write will take up less space as you can see. The decision to (not) use libraries/frameworks should be always made at the beginning.

Comment: Libraries such as jQuery allow you to write code that is cross-browser compatible and you don't have to think about it. When you add the jQuery click callback, you know it will fire and don't have to worry about the implementation details yourself - there have been many smart people working on it already. But again, if you use too many frameworks, your code size will go up. Just because your method is only 2 lines of code doesn't mean it's 2 lines of code - jQuery has to handle that method in the background somehow, so in the end, the code you write is shorter, not necessarily the total count.

Comment: That's why you need to decide up front how many frameworks and libraries you want to use, every additional one comes with an overhead. You see, the more you program the more it becomes a philosophy exercise haha. Back to your question, my Pen can be configured, you can pass the slides to it and it handles it for you. You can pause/resume the animation and add control buttons to move slides. Also, you could instantiate multiple carousels as it's a Class, and have different settings for every single one. It could be all done in jQuery too, I just like to write pure JavaScript whenever I can 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get this console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'removeClass' of undefined".

This error is because the code will run `i++` first, then run `images[i].removeClass('main-image-slider-right')...`.

```
images[i].removeClass('main-image-slider-left').addClass('main-image-slider-right').delay(100).queue(function() {
  // the 'i' is already added 1, so it may equal images[max], so you got that error
  images[i].removeClass('main-image-slider-right').addClass('main-image-slider-center').dequeue();
});
```

You can move `i++` into `queue`:

```
images[i].removeClass('main-image-slider-left').addClass('main-image-slider-right').delay(100).queue(function() {
  images[i].removeClass('main-image-slider-right').addClass('main-image-slider-center').dequeue();
  // after all the animation is done, at the end of queue update 'i'. 
  i++;
});
```

You can try this.

Note: don't forget to remove the `i++` at the end of code.

**Update**

Update the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8na2n5L2/1/) code

At the edge of slides it will not update the class with `if (images[i - 1])`, wee need always update the class of previous slide. So I changed the code to

```
images[i == 0 ? images.length - 1 : i - 1].removeClass('main-image-slider-center').addClass('main-image-slider-left');
```

Comment: Hey Haizhou, I don't work with jQuery, but why would it run i++ first when it's defined as the last operation in the function?

Comment: @Haizhou I added the fiddle here. This does not appear to be working, but it's one step closer: https://jsfiddle.net/8na2n5L2/

Comment: @Lubos that is because you `delay` the function for 100ms. Please check jsFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/b96zoph6/) .

Comment: @JordanCarter I updated the code, try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8na2n5L2/1/), we need always update the previous slide class.

Comment: @HaizhouLiu Thank you for all your help. It looks like I got it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8na2n5L2/2/). If you know a more efficient way, please feel free to let me know. I feel like what I'm doing is inefficient.

Comment: @HaizhouLiu Ah I see O:)